# сложности с использованием hasClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

Данный код проверяет элементы `div` c классом `form-field` на наличие у них так же класса `false_validation`. В проверке в первом `console.log` я вывожу результат элемента `(true)` если есть у него в списке класс `false_validation` и вывожу строку `'No class false_validation'`, если нет в списке классов этого класса. А во втором `console.log` я вывожу ВСЕ классы:

```
var ff = jQuery('div.form-field');
for (var i = 0; i < ff.length ; i++ ){
        if(ff.hasClass("false_validation")) {

           document.getElementsByClassName('form-field')[i].value = ''; // action

            if(ff.hasClass("false_validation")){
                console.log(ff.hasClass("false_validation")); // 1 console.log
            } else { console.log('No class false_validation');}
            console.log(ff[i].classList);                     // 2 console.log
        }
    }
```

Вывод консоли браузера:

```
true
(3) ["form-field", "form-name", "false_validation", value: "form-field form-name false_validation"]
true
(3) ["form-field", "form-tel", "false_validation", value: "form-field form-tel false_validation"]
true
(2) ["form-field", "form-city", value: "form-field form-city"]
true
(3) ["form-field", "form-email", "false_validation", value: "form-field form-email false_validation"]
true
(3) ["form-field", "form-password", "false_validation", value: "form-field form-password false_validation"]
true
(3) ["form-field", "form-password", "false_validation", value: "form-field form-password false_validation"]
true
(2) ["form-field", "form-accept", value: "form-field form-accept "]
true
(3) ["form-title", "form-field", "false_validation", value: "form-title form-field false_validation"]
```

Т.е. везде значение `true`!, даже если класса `false_validation`  в списке классов у элемента нет!Во всех источниках пишут применение в `hasClass` в таком виде:

```
$('#say').hasClass('meow')
```

Подскажите, почему у меня это условие не срабатывает?

Comment: Почему внутри цикла идет проверка на наличие класса у `ff`, а не у `ff[i]`? Также у вас 2 одниаковых вложенных проверки, на ветку `else` перехода никогда не будет

Comment: @yolosora, Вы правынемного не туда начал рыть проблема моя состоит в том, что НЕ срабатывает моя строка action  для элементов у которых есть класс false_validation. Мой action срабатывает для ВСЕХ элементов с классом form-field!

Comment: ну это похоже уже на совсем другую историю!

Comment: @yolosora, согласен. Напишите свой комментарий в ответе, я его прийму как ответ на свой вопрос!Вы на него, получается ответили. А свою ситуацию я опишу в другом вопросе. Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все просто. В переменной `ff` у Вас хранятся все элементы, попадающие под селектор. Вы используете hasClass не на каждый элемент, а на коллекцию элементов и эта функция работает по-другому - то есть она в этой коллекции находит хотя бы 1 класс `false_validation` и выдает true. Ваш код можно переделать так, используйте цикл `each` для коллекции `ff`

```js
var ff = jQuery('div.form-field');
ff.each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);

  if($this.hasClass("false_validation")) {
     $this.value = ''; // action
     console.log($this.hasClass("false_validation"))
  } else {
     console.log('No class false_validation');
     console.log($this.classList);  
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-field"></div>
<div class="form-field"></div>
<div class="form-field false_validation"></div>
<div class="form-field"></div>
<div class="form-field"></div>
```